# Objective C UIBarButtonItem as toggle button for edit and save

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem, ios8.3

I have written a code to place a right bar button item with customview.While selecting edit it changes to save option.Now I selecting save it saves the values.If again I try to select edit the action not firing.The code I written below,

```
item = [[UINavigationItem alloc]init];    
btnn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
btnn.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
btnn.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
[btnn addTarget:self action:@selector(rightBarButtonCustomPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem* rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnn];   
item.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn;
self.navigationBar.items = @[item];
```

-(IBAction)rightBarButtonCustomPressed:(UIBarButtonItem*)btn
{

```
item = [[UINavigationItem alloc]init];
btnn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[btnn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
btnn.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
btnn.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
[btnn addTarget:self action:@selector(saveBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnn setTitle:@"save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem* rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnn];
item.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn;       
self.navigationBar.items = @[item];

[self.firstNameText setEnabled:YES];
[self.lastNameText setEnabled:YES];
[self.dateOfBirthTxt setEnabled:YES];
[self.contactNumberlbl setEnabled:YES];
```

}

-(IBAction)saveBtnClicked:(UIBarButtonItem*)btn {

```
[self.firstNameText setEnabled:NO];
[self.lastNameText setEnabled:NO];
[self.dateOfBirthTxt setEnabled:NO];
[self.contactNumberlbl setEnabled:NO];
item = [[UINavigationItem alloc]init];
btnn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
btnn.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
btnn.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
[btnn addTarget:self action:@selector(rightBarButtonCustomPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem* rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnn];
item.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn;   
self.navigationBar.items = @[item];
```

I need to achieve barbuttonitem as toggle to save and edit option.Please anybody help me to fix this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In place of alloc init evry time , why don't you try changing buttonTitle and then you can perform action on basis of it